# store result of select query into array variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to store the result of this sql query in variable `@a`. The result contains 17 rows. How to edit this code in order to store the rows in `@a`?

```
declare @a uniqueidentifier
select EnrollmentID into @a  from Enrollment
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot store 17 values inside a *scalar* variable. You can use a *table* variable instead.

This is how you can declare it:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (id uniqueidentifier)
```

and how you can populate it with values from `Enrollment` table:

```
INSERT INTO @a 
SELECT EnrollmentID FROM Enrollment
```

Answer (score 4):

You should declare @a as a Table Variable with one column of type unique identifier as follows:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (uniqueId uniqueidentifier); 

INSERT INTO @a
SELECT EnrollmentID 
FROM Enrollment;
```

Comment: how your answer is different from the accepted answer ?